Standard way to map handler-thrown exceptions to IActionResults in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API?
The API controllers in my new ASP.NET Core 8 Web API use MediatR to dispatch requests to handlers. Handlers may throw exceptions; when that happens, the controllers appear to be returning generic status 500 regardless of the exception.
Is there something built into .NET Core that will handle the basic mappings from Exception to IActionResult, like mapping a BadHttpRequestException to a BadRequestResult and a NotFoundException to a NotFoundResult?
I do see there's an app.UseExceptionHandler for creating something custom but I'm not sure that's applicable and I don't want to create something custom if there's already a built-in.

There is no built-in method for mapping exceptions to specific IActionResult types. UseExceptionHandler is applicable and effective for handling such mapping and other more custom needs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0
Another way would be Exception filters but it is not as flexible as UseExceptionHandler so it is more recommended to apply UseExceptionHandler.
